# Templated class truncating doubles

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++14

I am working on an assignment for an introductory C++ class and have been butting my head against this problem for three days.  I have a templated class that is meant to accept any data type, and while I can declare objects of type double, the decimal gets truncated when I actually try to initialize them.

I'm not sure what all is important, so please let me know if I included to much or too little.  Below is the class definition:

```
template <class T>
class MyClass
{
    private:
        int x;
        int y;

    public:
        const typedef T value_type;
        static const int DEFAULT_VALUE;

        MyClass(value_type newX = DEFAULT_VALUE, 
                value_type newY = DEFAULT_VALUE);
        void setX(value_type newX);
        void setY(value_type newY);
        T getX() const;
        T getY() const;
        void print() const;
};

template <class T>
const int MyClass<T>::DEFAULT_VALUE = int();
```

Here is the implementation:

```
template <class T>
OrderedPair<T>::OrderedPair(T newX, T newY)
{
    setX(newX);
    setY(newY);
}

template <class T>
void MyClass<T>::setX(value_type newX)
{
    x = newX;
}

template <class T>
void MyClass<T>::setY(value_type newY)
{
    y= newY;
}

template <class T>
T MyClass<T>::getX() const
{
    return x;
}

template <class T>
T MyClass<T>::getY() const
{
    return y;
}

template <class T>
void MyClass<T>::print() const
{
    std::cout << "(" << getX() << ", " << getY() << ")";
}
```

Here is the client code:

```
MyClass<double> set;

set.setFirst(9.99);
set.setSecond(13.34);
set.print();
```

And here is the output:

```
(9, 13)
```

Edited typos in my copy-paste of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

private variables **x** and **y** should be type T instead of int.  That's why values are being truncated.

```
template <class T>
class MyClass
{
    public:
        const typedef T value_type;
        static const int DEFAULT_VALUE;

    private:
        value_type x;
        value_type y;

        MyClass(value_type newX = DEFAULT_VALUE, 
                value_type newY = DEFAULT_VALUE);
        void setX(value_type newX);
        void setY(value_type newY);
        T getX() const;
        T getY() const;
        void print() const;
};

template <class T>
const int MyClass<T>::DEFAULT_VALUE = int();
```

Comment: Thank you, your thoroughness is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You declared your member variables as `int`, not `T`/`value_type`, so while you can pass in anything that can convert to `int`, they're immediately assigned to `int` and additional information is lost. Template the type of the member variables too, e.g. instead of

```
    int x;
    int y;
```

do

```
    T x; // Or value_type, though you may need to reorder declarations
    T y;
```